# endsWith with array in ES6

Tags: ecmascript-6

I learning ES6 and try to use new for me `endsWith`. Before this I used `includes` in some of my scripts, and I thought that mechanic will be same. I picked a casual task: I have domains list and want to filter all "cn" domains. Logic is:

```
let ends = [".cn",".tw",".jp"]
for(let i=0;i<arrayOfDomains.length;i++){
  const host = /https?:\/\/(www\.)?([a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9]+/.exec(arrayOfDomains[i])[0];
  console.log(host.endsWith(ends))
}
```

and result of `console.log` all `false`. Is there a way to use array in `endsWith`?

Comment: [No, it takes one string and optionally one number.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there isn't a way to use an array in endsWith, one option is to declare another function that uses the ends array and host variable as parameters to check it.

You can try something like this:

```
let ends = [".cs", ".com"];
let host = "www.page.com";
let hostEndsWith = (host, ends) => {
    let value = false;
    value = ends.some(element => {
        return host.endsWith(element);
    });
    console.log(value);
};

hostEndsWith(host, ends);
```

You can copy that code in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) to test it.

Here is the information about the endsWith function [endsWith informartion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith)

I hope this helps you!